# Obtener datos de un dataframe entre un rango de valores - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Quiero obtener los datos que tengo en un dataframe entre dos fechas y por ahora lo he conseguido. La cosa es que yo lo hago mediante un `bucle for` y me da la sensación que `Pandas` debe tener una solución propia mucho más directa.

Una de las premisas de mi dataframe es que está ordenado por fecha y hora, por lo tanto nunca aparecerá un dato en una fila cualquiera.

Por ahora este es mi código,

```
for i in range(date_start[1], date_end[1]+1):
    cnt = 0
    new_df = df[(df['Dia'] == i) & (df['Mes'] == month) & (df['Año'] == year) & (df['Node name'] == node)]
    # Si la longitud del dataframe es mayor a 0 significa que tenemos datos de ese día
    if len(new_df)>0:
        # Guardamos datos en una lista y la recorremos viendo si la diferencia es mayor a 1.
        paquetes = new_df['Num secuencia'].tolist()
        for r in range(len(paquetes)-1):
            dif = paquetes[r+1]-paquetes[r]
            if dif > 1:
                cnt = cnt + (dif-1)

        result.append(cnt)
    # No hay datos de ese día
    else:
        result.append(0)

    print('Paquetes perdidos el dia ',i,':',cnt)
```

Básicamente el objetivo es comprobar si en mi columna `Num secuencia` los números son correlativos o si se han producido saltos.

En cuanto a la duda, lo que hago es un `for` que empieza en el día de inicio y acaba en el último día (+1 para que el for mire ese día). Y cómo se que está ordenado voy mirando día a día la información.

La cosa es que yo creo que de alguna manera `pandas`quizás permite definir un inicio y un final y estudiar todos los valores de en medio.

Comment: te refieres al primer for? o al segundo?

Answer (score 2):

Si no entendí mal, tu problema pasaría por **(a)** armar grupos por `Dia`, `Mes`, `Año` y `Node name`, **(b)** obtener las diferencias entre cada `Num secuencia` en cada grupo **(c)** filtrar las diferencias mayores a 1, para saber dónde hay saltos de secuencia.

Esto en `pandas` podría resolverse de la siguiente forma:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Node name':['A','A','A','A','A'],
                   'Dia':[6,7,7,8,8],
                   'Mes':[1,1,1,1,1],
                   'Año':[2020,2020,2020,2020,2020],
                   'Num secuencia': [5,6,8,11,12]
                   })


df['diff'] = df.groupby(['Node name', 'Dia', 'Mes','Año'])['Num secuencia'].diff().fillna(0)
print(df)

  Node name  Dia  Mes   Año  Num secuencia  diff
0         A    6    1  2020              5   0.0
1         A    7    1  2020              6   0.0
2         A    7    1  2020              8   2.0
3         A    8    1  2020             11   0.0
4         A    8    1  2020             12   1.0

print(df[df['diff'] > 1])

  Node name  Dia  Mes   Año  Num secuencia  diff
2         A    7    1  2020              8   2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo que te entendí es que necesitas evaluar `Num secuencia` pero que no necesitas mirar todos los valores, solo los de algunas fechas.

```
#Filtramos por fecha, en este caso solo año 2016
df=df[df["Año"]=='2016']

#Agregamos la columnma Dif, para poder luego verificar los CONSECUTIVOS en "Num secuencia"
df["Dif"]=df["Num secuencia"].diff()

#Para que sean consecutivos la diferencia debe ser de 1, filtramos por ese numero
df=df[df["Dif"]==1]
```

En caso que quieras lo contrario podes hacer != en lugar de ==

Saludos y déjanos saber que solución te sirvió y porque?